# Ext JS 5 : shared viewcontroller

Tags: javascript

I have a little question. Is it possible to share a ViewController ?

I have a Ext.grid.Panel. This component use one viewcontroller. When I want to edit a row, my program open a Ext.window.Window with a Ext.form.Form inside. I want to use the same viewcontroller instance of my grid. I can use setController but when I close my form, I think the shared viewcontroller is destroy.

Is it possible to do that ?

Jean-Marc